I have a filter that runs every 5 seconds. When I open another spreadsheet the filter stops. How do I make the filter workbook specific?
When I open or just select another workbook while this is running the macro stops at the line noted below.
Your thoughts appreciated!!
Sub ONE()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rngDatabase As Range
    Dim rngCriteria As Range
    'define the database and criteria ranges
    Set rngDatabase = wb.Worksheets("myLIST").Range("A3:Z5000") '  STOPS HERE
    Set rngCriteria = wb.Worksheets("ONE").Range("A3:Z4")
    'copy the filtered data to an alternative location
    rngDatabase.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=rngCriteria,                 CopyToRange:=wb.Worksheets("ONE").Range("A5:Z5010"), Unique:=True
    'sorts data onfilters
     With wb.Application.Worksheets("ONE")
         wb.Worksheets("ONE").Range("A6:Z5000").Sort Key1:=wb.Worksheets("ONE").Range("U6"), Order1:=xlAscending
     End With       
End Sub


Iirc, Excel is single threaded and can only do one thing at a time. You should only do something in between code when the code requires input from the user. Why exactly are you running it every 5 seconds?

I use it for trading.  Is there really not a way to make the code specific to the workbook?

Also, I am not running any code in the other spreadsheet.  Just selecting it.

You could open a new instance of Excel to let your one instance do the constant filter refreshing and the other to do other things in. I don't know of a way to do things in the same instance while a code is running.

Many thx---I think that works!!
